# Retrieve Uploaded Blob with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that is creating a blob and posting it to a PHP file. Here is my code:

**HTML/Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function upload() {

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('user', 'person');

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
      // Uploaded.
    };

    var blob = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'});

    oReq.send(blob);
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="upload()">Click Me!</button>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

When I look at my developer console, I am not getting any $_POST data on my PHP page. I need to know how to retrieve the text file being posted to PHP script.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data from the blob can be read from `php://input`, as in

```
<?php
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

If however you want to send multiple pieces of data with a form data object it would be like a normal multipart/form-data post. All string would be available through `$_POST` and all blobs and file through `$_FILES`.

```
function upload() {

    var data = new FormData();
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
      // Uploaded.
    };

    var blob = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'});
    data.append('file', blob);
    oReq.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code above. I know see the content of the file 'string(6) "abc123"' in the developer console. How would I go about being able to access the blob through the `$_FILES` array? I updated my javascript with `oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` this but it still does not allow me to access the blob through the `$_FILES` array. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to use a FormData object and append the blob to it and pass the Formdata object to `XMLHttpRequest.send` .

Comment: I am great with PHP, but not with javascript. Do you mind updating your code in your answer to include the FormData method you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you so much! I can now access it! Last question. How would I know save this blob (meaning the actual .txt file) in a "texts" directory on my server? To be more clear, how to I convert this blob into an actual text file?

Comment: Take a look at the php manual for file upload via post http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: The whole day looking for a simple answer like that ... Many thanks from NY

Answer (score 0):

Append your Blob to FormData and send it instead.