# Upload a Blob image using JavaScript to a PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php

I have an image created with a JavaScript Blob which I need to upload to a PHP script.

My JavaScript upload function...

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://requestb.in/17m14c51', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    //
  };

  // Listen to the upload progress.
  //var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      console.log((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
      //progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}
```

This URL http://requestb.in/17m14c51?inspect shows the data that this code is posting.

My Image is coming in as an image.  I am not sure how to access this image in my PHP script though as I do not see any form or file name, maybe  I am missing it?

Previously my PHP had the image come in as Base64 so this PHP below did the upload...

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {

    //$output_file_new= $output_file.'-'.md5(time().uniqid()).'.jpg';
    $output_file_new= $output_file;

    $ifp = fopen($output_file_new, "wb");
    $base64_string2 = urldecode($base64_string);
    $data = explode(',', $base64_string2);
    $decoded = base64_decode($data[1]);

    fwrite($ifp, $decoded);
    fclose($ifp);


    echo json_encode(array('img_url' => $output_file_new, 'headers' => parseRequestHeaders()));
    //return $output_file_new;
}
```

Now that I am not getting it as Base64, how can I save it in my PHP?

Comment: `xhttp.send("file=blobOrFile");` and access it like `$_POST['file']`

Comment: @Rayon thanks I just saw that is how I can send other params and name them thanks.  Ill delete or if you post answer will accept

Comment: Better to delete it... Good Luck :)

Comment: @Rayon I just tested and result was this... RAW BODY `bookmarkid=123456&blob=[object Blob]` so my image was now missing from the post http://requestb.in/17m14c51?inspect#18o16n

Comment: Try using [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)  or `javascript` [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), `php` [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101609/retrieve-uploaded-blob-with-php

Comment: Is `blobOrFile` result of `toDataURL` ?

Comment: @Rayon A `Blob` is not a `data URI`

Comment: @Rayon The blob is created from a dataURI

Comment: @guest271314 I think FormData(), is the solution as I need to post other data with the blob too

Comment: @JasonDavis, Not sure why you want to send `blob`.. A string returned by `toDataURL` will do...

Comment: @Rayon when generating really large images the datauri is not good and thats when I switch to Blob/  Its part of my Chrome extension for generating full page length screenshots