# Upload captured audio to server. JS Jquery PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this

```
<button onclick="startRecording(this);">record</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>stop</button>

  <h2>Recordings</h2>
  <ul id="recordingslist"></ul>

  <h2>Log</h2>
  <pre id="log"></pre>

  <script>
  function __log(e, data) {
    log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
  }

  var audio_context;
  var recorder;

  function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    __log('Media stream created.' );
    __log("input sample rate " +input.context.sampleRate);

    // Feedback!
    //input.connect(audio_context.destination);
    __log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

    recorder = new Recorder(input, {
                  numChannels: 1
                });
    __log('Recorder initialised.');
  }

  function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
  }

  function stopRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Stopped recording.');

    // create WAV download link using audio data blob
    createDownloadLink();

    recorder.clear();
  }

  function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      /*var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);*/
    });
  }

  window.onload = function init() {
    try {
      // webkit shim
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      audio_context = new AudioContext;
      __log('Audio context set up.');
      __log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
    } catch (e) {
      alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });
  };
  </script>

   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="recordmp3.js"></script>
```

To capture audio and offer an mp3 download but what I really need to do is upload the recordings to the server and as a bonus if I could rename the files before upload that would make it perfect! Can't show an example of what I've tried as I have no idea where to start on this one, any help greatly appreciated.

The flow would be to capture a handful of short recordings, rename them then hit an upload button which will upload them as mp3's then redirect to a success page.

Full code here https://github.com/Audior/Recordmp3js

Comment: You need AJAX to upload the data

Comment: May I know, after or during which action, you want to upload the audio?

Comment: @BattleHawk after it creates the mp3 i would think, so after function createDownloadLink()

Comment: The flow would be to capture a handful of short recordings, rename them then hit an upload button which will upload them as mp3's then redirect to a success page.

@ADyson AJAX would not be needed in this case as after renaming I can hit an "upload button" to initiate the upload.

Comment: It would, because the data is in memory in the JavaScript. A regular postback would not be able to see it. your upload button will need to trigger an AJAX request

Comment: Still need help with this, just uploading the file it creates would be a massive help :-/

Comment: If you can take a different (and more modern) approach, I [forked](https://github.com/moshfeu/web-dictaphone) the [MDN recorder demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API) and added the submission to a php server. If this works for you, I can put it as an answer.

Comment: @GlenKeybit To where u want to upload the mp3?

Comment: @MoshFeu I have tested your fork and have 2 issues, the first is I only seem to get the first 1-2sec recording no matter how long I wait before pressing "stop" and the second is I don't see any "upload" button?

Comment: @ashenmadusanka in a directory called recordings which is in the same directory as the code.

Comment: I'll check the first issue. For the second point. It just upload the audio right away. It's very simple to add a button and upload it upon click

Comment: @MoshFeu on further testing it records fine on chrome but not firefox. I have worked out it 'just uploads' which is great, and I can work out how to add a button now I've studied the code. How do I make it upload to /uploads (in the same directory) instead of the directory the code is in?

Comment: I've also worked out how to move them to a directory now, so really it is just that I cuts the recording short on Firefox (desktop and mobile) that I'm stuck with now.

Comment: The reason it works on Chrome is because the file type if indeed mp3 but the encoding is `.ogg`. I've elaborated in [a comment](https://github.com/moshfeu/web-dictaphone/tree/7ec33c3fbdf0eb981790959c0efa7fa03175e659#comment). About the destination folder, you can change the path to whatever you want. Just add the path to `move_uploaded_file($audio, 'path/to/uploads/$name.'.ogg');` (replace `path/to/uploads` with the real path of course)

Comment: @MoshFeu I've started a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231409/web-dictaphone-discussion

Comment: I found [the issue](https://github.com/moshfeu/web-dictaphone/commit/e344645969835af0d7bf1f93df15439b787cfbc3). Seems like FF needs to create Blobs often. Seems like with one big Blob it loses some data. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start#parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upload the data as a XMLHttpRequest, however on the server side you should save it to a file with a custom name. This is also safer, since you can very easily avoid file traversal attacks by not specifying a path (From what I've understood, other people can't upload files to your computer/server, however I still believe you should approach this method because it is a great introduction to protecting an application with basic security measures).

You can use the following (modified) answer, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25101647/11985743), to do the job. This is how the JS function `createDownloadLink` should look after the modifications:

```js
function createDownloadLink() {
  recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
    // Generate the 'File'
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', blob);

    // Make the HTTP request
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // POST the data to upload.php
    oReq.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
      // Data has been uploaded
    };
    oReq.send(data);
  });
}
```

On the PHP side, however, you should also make some modifications, since this is now a classic file upload, rather than a POST request with the data being sent as a parameter. Modify `upload.php` like so (information about moving uploaded files taken from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)):

```php
<?php
// Make sure recordings folder exists
if(!is_dir("recordings")){
    $res = mkdir("recordings",0777); 
}

// Declare file name
$filename = 'recordings/' . 'audio_recording_' . date( 'Y-m-d-H-i-s' ) .'.mp3';

// Move the uploaded file to the directory
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filename));
?>
```